# For loop displaying 3 6 9 instead of 1 2 3

Tags: java, for-loop

I was trying to code a simple `for` loop program.

The user enters a number (for example 4) and the program will display "Trading day 1/2/3/4" every time the user clicks the "next day" button.

But my `for` loop is displaying 3 6 9 12 instead and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

The program gets value that the user entered in the input box and changes it to `int`.

```java
public class startButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
        tradingDaysValue = Integer.parseInt(tradingDaysField.getText());
    }
```

This is the code under another button listener after the program gets the value from the previous button listener.

```java
public class tradeButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tradingDaysValue; i++) {
            tradingDayCounter++;
            tradingDayLabel.setText("TRADING DAY " + tradingDayCounter);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm unsure why it's displaying 3 6 9 instead of 1 2 3.

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to your question and avoid tag spamming.

Comment: First hint: where the code says `tradingDayLabel.setText("TRADING DAY " + tradingDayCounter);`, do you think that `tradingDayLabel` will **change during the loop**? Therefore, when `actionPerformed` is called, how many different labels will be changed? How many times will each label be changed? Second hint: how many times does `actionPerformed` get called? Does the value of `tradingDayLabel` change **between the calls**? Therefore, which label gets changed the first time? The second time, etc.? Third hint: **between calls** to `actionPerformed`, **does `tradingDayCounter` change**?

Comment: Before posting debugging questions on Stack Overflow, please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ , and [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to: a) think carefully about the intended logic of the code, and therefore exactly **what is expected to happen** at each step when the code runs; b) carefully **check what does** happen at each step and compare it to that expectation; c) **think** about any difference. If you cannot find an explanation, then create a proper [mre] that **focuses on** the part that behaves strangely.

Comment: Also: think carefully about the requirements for the code. "The user enters a number (for eg 4) and the program will display "Trading day 1/2/3/4" everytime the user clicks the "next day" button" - When the user enters the number, **what does that number mean**? How does it change the expected result from repeatedly clicking the button?

Comment: Another hint: Does it make sense to run a loop **every time** the button is clicked?

Comment: Stepping through the code should make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `actionPerformed` for `tradeButtonListener` is executing every time the button is pressed, and this function contains the whole loop. Therefore, the loop gets executed each time you press the button. For example, if your number is 4, four iterations will run each time you press the next day button (effectively increasing the counter four times and setting the text four times), netting you increments of 4: 4,8,12,16.

For what you want, you should only do a ++ for the `tradingDayCounter` each time you click the `tradeButton`, which only happens in the counter is `<` than the `tradingDaysValue`.

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent event) {
  if (tradingDayCounter < tradingDaysValue) {
    tradingDayCounter++;
    tradingDayLabel.setText("TRADING DAY " + tradingDayCounter);
  }
}
```